# How do I uninstall another windows 10 in my laptop?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

After installing an SSD I performed a clean install of windows 10 in the SSD. But windows 10 of previous HDD is still in the bootmanager. As a result when I start the PC , it gives two prompt (Windows on partition 9 and Windows on partition 2). But I want to remove the windows on partition 2. How do I do that?
[this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/888023) option doesn't apply to windows 10 as there is no boot.ini file.

Comment: I use [BCDEdit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx) in a case like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BCDEdit application to alter what shows up in the boot list.

But, I presume you've already physically removed the partition 2?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: If all you do is alter the boot menu, you don't recover all the space wasted by the extra Windows install.

Answer (score 0):

GO to run and type following command:

**msconfig**

It will show the System Configuration Windows:

select the tab named **Boot**. In that you will find 2 OS listed in boot manager. one is your current OS and the other one is the your last installed Os's entry. select your last installed OS entry and delete it.

Press OK button and restart the system. your problem is solved  !!!

Answer (score -1):

Simply copy all the important files from the HDD onto your SSD temporarily, then format the drive or delete the partition.  Then, just copy the files back onto the fresh partition on the HDD.

Comment: This seems a ton of extra work, for something that can solved within a minute, by simply editing the boot menu.

Comment: @Ramhound It is a waste of space to simply edit the boot menu and leave an entire unused Windows installation.